# When I add a string column I get an unsupported operand type when using pct_change?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sample dataset is below. I'm not sure why the code doesn't work here:

```
import pandas as pd
w = pd.Series(['BAIN', 'BAIN', 'BAIN', 'KPMG', 'KPMG', 'KPMG', 'EY', 'EY', 'EY' ])
x = pd.Series([2020,2019,2018,2020,2019,2018,2020,2019,2018])
y = pd.Series([10000, 10000, 20000, 25000, 50000, 10000, 100000, 50500, 120000])
z = pd.Series([100000, 500000, 1000000, 50000, 100000, 40000, 1000, 500, 4000])
# aa = pd.Series(['Data', 'Data', 'Data', 'Legal', 'Legal', 'Legal', 'Finance', 'Finance', 'Finance'])
# df = pd.DataFrame({'consultant': w, 'fiscal_year':x, 'budgeted_cost':y, 'actual_cost':z, 'department':aa})
df = pd.DataFrame({'consultant': w, 'fiscal_year':x, 'budgeted_cost':y, 'actual_cost':z})

indexer_consultant_fy = ['consultant', 'fiscal_year']
df = df.set_index(indexer_consultant_fy).sort_index(ascending=True)
df['budgeted_percent_change_by_year'] = df.groupby(level=['consultant'])['budgeted_cost'].pct_change(fill_method='ffill')
df['actual_percent_change_by_year'] = df.groupby(level=['consultant'])['actual_cost'].pct_change(fill_method='ffill')
df = df.sort_values(by = ['consultant', 'fiscal_year'], ascending=False)
df['actual_budget_pct_diff'] = df.pct_change(axis='columns',fill_method='ffill')['actual_cost']
```

However, when I add one more column that has a string called department. This does not work. I get TypeError that says:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

This is the code sample that does not work:

```
import pandas as pd
w = pd.Series(['BAIN', 'BAIN', 'BAIN', 'KPMG', 'KPMG', 'KPMG', 'EY', 'EY', 'EY' ])
x = pd.Series([2020,2019,2018,2020,2019,2018,2020,2019,2018])
y = pd.Series([10000, 10000, 20000, 25000, 50000, 10000, 100000, 50500, 120000])
z = pd.Series([100000, 500000, 1000000, 50000, 100000, 40000, 1000, 500, 4000])
aa = pd.Series(['Data', 'Data', 'Data', 'Legal', 'Legal', 'Legal', 'Finance', 'Finance', 'Finance'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'consultant': w, 'fiscal_year':x, 'budgeted_cost':y, 'actual_cost':z, 'department':aa})

indexer_consultant_fy = ['consultant', 'fiscal_year']
df = df.set_index(indexer_consultant_fy).sort_index(ascending=True)
df['budgeted_percent_change_by_year'] = df.groupby(level=['consultant'])['budgeted_cost'].pct_change(fill_method='ffill')
df['actual_percent_change_by_year'] = df.groupby(level=['consultant'])['actual_cost'].pct_change(fill_method='ffill')
df = df.sort_values(by = ['consultant', 'fiscal_year'], ascending=False)
df['actual_budget_pct_diff'] = df.pct_change(axis='columns',fill_method='ffill')['actual_cost']
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the last line?

Comment: The goal was actually to get the percent change between the actual_cost and budgeted_cost.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you add the department column, your last line tries to take the percent change on all columns, including the departments. So it is trying to take `(Data - 100000) / 100000`, or something of the like, which makes no sense. It didn't happen before with the consultant column because you are setting that as the index, and it is therefore ignored.

Assuming you are trying to just get the percentage change of the `actual_cost` column, change the last line to:

```
df['actual_budget_pct_diff'] = df['actual_cost'].pct_change(fill_method='ffill')
```

Comment: Thanks. The goal was actually to get the percent change between the actual_cost and budgeted_cost.